# (SQLite) Selecting # separated data as multiple rows

Tags: sql, sqlite, concatenation, aggregation, string-concatenation

I have a table wihch contains foreign keys concactenated (separator #) in a field. I want to transform the data to one row per FK so that I can do a join on the data.

My table looks like this:
ARCHE
id_a | str_ids

str_ids field contains concactenate FK as follows: #id1#id2#id4#id7#
(There is a different number of agregated id's for each row)

I am not really familiar with SQLite, and I have trouble finding the equivalent. I understood I have to do this "with recursive" but it seems I can't get the hang of this.

The oracle equivalent of what I am looking for is as follows:

```
select 
    id_a
    ,trim(regexp_substr(str_ids, '[^#]+', 1, LEVEL)) as id_b          
from arche
connect by trim(regexp_substr(str_ids, '[^#]+', 1, LEVEL)) IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQLite you can use a recursive common table expression to solve this. The recursive CTE selects from the original table and splits the strings into subparts, which the main query selects from.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte(id, val, etc) AS(
    SELECT id_a, '', str_ids FROM arche
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        id
        , SUBSTR(etc, 0, INSTR(etc, '#'))
        , SUBSTR(etc, INSTR(etc, '#')+1)
    FROM cte
    WHERE etc <> ''
)
SELECT id AS id_a, REPLACE(val, 'id', '') AS id_b
FROM cte
WHERE val <> ''
ORDER BY id, val
```

Here is an example :

**Schema (SQLite v3.26)**

---

**Query #1**

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte(id, val, etc) AS(
    SELECT 1, '', '#id1#id2#id4#id7#'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        id
        , SUBSTR(etc, 0, INSTR(etc, '#'))
        , SUBSTR(etc, INSTR(etc, '#')+1)
    FROM cte
    WHERE etc <> ''
)
SELECT id AS id_a, val AS id_b
FROM cte
WHERE val <> ''
ORDER BY id, val;
```

```
| id_a | id_b |
| ---- | ---- |
| 1    | id1  |
| 1    | id2  |
| 1    | id4  |
| 1    | id7  |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iU6xCEoqjry5Mi36J6Y6rv/1)

NB2 :

- `REGEXP_REPLACE` does not exists in SQLite, I replaced it with `REPLACE`
- you need a `#` ad the end of string for this to work (having two #` is ok, too)
- this is not a very performant approach ; if you have lots of rows to process, this might not scale well.